# Connection's current state is open error

Tags: c#

I have encountered the following error:

> The Connection was not closed. The
>   Connection's current state is open Invalid attempt to call MetaData
>   when reader is closed.

I tried this:

```
while(dr.Read()){//and  set value}
```

but it doesn't work. This is how it is done in some of the other forms that work.

This code is run when I press Enter in my application. When I press it the first time, the error is shown, but when I press Enter a second time, with the same data, it works.

```
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectknittingdaily", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@m_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt_id.Text);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Text = dr[0].ToString();
        textBox1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
        machineno_combo.Text = dr[2].ToString();
        guage_combo.Text = dr[3].ToString();
        gsm_combo.Text = dr[4].ToString();
        count_combo.Text = dr[5].ToString();
        color_combo.Text = dr[6].ToString();
        supplier_combo.Text = dr[7].ToString();
        txt_rollsfrom.Text = dr[8].ToString();
        txt_rollsto.Text = dr[9].ToString();
        txt_rolls.Text = dr[10].ToString();
        txt_totalweight.Text = dr[11].ToString();
        quality_combo.Text = dr[12].ToString();
        txt_cotton.Text = dr[13].ToString();
        txt_polyster.Text = dr[14].ToString();
        txt_elasthan.Text = dr[15].ToString();
        txt_modal.Text = dr[16].ToString();
        txt_tensil.Text = dr[17].ToString();
        txt_organic.Text = dr[18].ToString();
        border_combo.Text = dr[19].ToString();
    }
    dr.Close();
    //con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally 
{ 
    con.Close(); 
}
```

> Here Is My Sql Stored Procedure

```
create proc selectknittingdaily
@m_id int
as
begin
select master_knittingdaily.date2,master_order.program_no,machine.machine_no,machine.guage,
machine.gsm,yarn.yarn_count,(select color.color_no from yarn LEFT JOIN color on yarn.color_id=color.color_id 
where yarn.yarn_id=(select yarn_id from master_knittingdaily where m_id=@m_id))
,(select supplier_knitting.supplier_name from yarn LEFT JOIN supplier_knitting on
yarn.supplier_id=supplier_knitting.supplier_id
where yarn.yarn_id=(select yarn_id from master_knittingdaily where m_id=@m_id))
,master_knittingdaily.rolls_from,
master_knittingdaily.rolls_to,master_knittingdaily.total_rolls,master_knittingdaily.total_weight,
quality_knitting.quality_code,quality_knitting.cotton,quality_knitting.polyster,quality_knitting.elasthan,
quality_knitting.modal,quality_knitting.tensil,quality_knitting.organic,master_knittingdaily.border
from master_knittingdaily
LEFT JOIN master_order on master_knittingdaily.order_id=master_order.order_id
LEFT JOIN machine on master_knittingdaily.machine_id=machine.machine_id
LEFT JOIN yarn on master_knittingdaily.yarn_id=yarn.yarn_id
LEFT JOIN quality_knitting on master_knittingdaily.quality_id=quality_knitting.quality_id
where master_knittingdaily.m_id=@m_id
end
```

Comment: Please, post a stack trace. Or at least show us the line that throws an error.

Comment: This suggests, strongly, to me that you're attempting to share a single connection object across multiple methods. Don't do this. It's far safer to create a new connection object in each place you need a connection, open it, use it and close it. Let the framework do its connection pooling magic and maintain the right number of actual connections in the background.

Comment: As an aside, you might want to read [Using table aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx): "The readability of a `SELECT` statement can be improved by giving a table an alias"

Comment: yahooo one error will fix i can replace datareader to dataTable but connection erorr still shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Problem is solve now because i can replace `SqlDataReader` to
>   `DataTable` and `connection` error also fix thx for giving ur ideas but
>   still is question y `SqlDataReader` not work

Answer (score 0):

just insert one code before you open your db connection

```
 if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        con.Close();

 con.Open();
```

Also add below code

```
dr.close();
  dr.dispose();
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: its not working same thing i'm using in finally{con.Close();} but i also try ur code its not working

Comment: no working first time on enter press only 4 values show and errors shown and second time all values shown on textboxes

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Using statement](http://www.dotnetperls.com/using) for database connectivity, this helps to manage resources.

**The using statement is combined with a type that implements *IDisposable***.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(//connection string)
  {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcname, con))
     {
       try{
           con.open();
           //data reader code
       }
       catch
       {

       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: i also try this but not working if u wanna see my procedure how data will come i will post

Comment: i was try like this using(SQlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(storedprocedurename,con)){}

Comment: @user2491383 If possible post the relevant data related to database connection, that would be fine.

Comment: @user2491383 Do you have any other cmd to execute?